# How to replace NULL values with an empty string in a dynamic pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @archivedate date = '5/1/2019'; 

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP((SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(DISTINCT ratechangedate) datecount
                FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive]
                WHERE ArchiveDate = @archivedate
                GROUP BY account
                ORDER BY datecount DESC)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)        
SELECT @cols = (SELECT REPLACE( '
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN ratechangedate END) AS [date <<index_num>>]
    ,MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN new_noterate END)   AS [rate <<index_num>>]' , '<<index_num>>', n)
            FROM cteTally
            ORDER BY n
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

set @query = 
N'WITH a AS (
    SELECT a.account,
        dense_rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY ratechangedate) AS index_num,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ratechangedate,101)[ratechangedate],
        new_noterate
    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
    WHERE archivedate = @date
    )
SELECT a.account' + @cols + N' 
FROM a
GROUP BY a.Account;'


EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@date datetime', @date = @archivedate;
```

Which produces this output:

[image]

I want to remove the `NULL` values and replace it with an empty string I tried just putting `ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ratechangedate,101),'')` and `ISNULL(new_noterate,'')` in the @query part of the code but I get these errors:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
> Invalid column name 'ratechangedate'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> Invalid column name 'ratechangedate'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
> Invalid column name 'ratechangedate'.
>
> ...... and so on for every other "line" up to a value of 34 .......

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the part you changed look like now? Because outside of requiring 2x the quotation marks (e.g. `ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ratechangedate,101),'''')`) , I don't see any reason it would error (and if the quotation marks were the issue, I don't think that would be the error). Did the column alias change?

Comment: @ZLK That does not get rid of the nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX), @archivedate DATE = '2019-01-05'; 

DECLARE @HowMany INT = 
                (
                    SELECT TOP(1) COUNT(DISTINCT a.ratechangedate) AS [datecount]
                    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
                    WHERE a.ArchiveDate = @archivedate
                    GROUP BY a.account
                    ORDER BY [datecount] DESC
                )
;
WITH E(n) AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n))
    ,E2(n) AS (SELECT a.n FROM E a CROSS JOIN E b)
    ,E4(n) AS (SELECT a.n FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b)
    ,cteTally(n) AS (SELECT TOP(@HowMany) ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n FROM E4)      
SELECT @cols = (SELECT REPLACE( N'
    ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN ratechangedate END)),'''') AS [date <<index_num>>]
    ,COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255),NULLIF(MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = <<index_num>> THEN new_noterate END),0)),'''') AS [rate <<index_num>>]
                ' 
                , '<<index_num>>', n)
            FROM cteTally
            ORDER BY n
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
;

SET @query = 
N'WITH ct AS (
    SELECT a.account
        ,DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY a.account ORDER BY a.ratechangedate) AS [index_num]
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.ratechangedate,101) AS [ratechangedate]
        ,a.new_noterate
    FROM MARS_DW.[dbo].[vw_GTMScheduledRateAndPaymentChangesWithAccountNumber_Archive] a
    WHERE a.archivedate = @date
)
SELECT ct.Account' + @cols + N' 
FROM ct
GROUP BY ct.Account;'

--PRINT @query;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@date DATETIME', @date = @archivedate;
```

Comment: Super close but I get ) AS [date 3]      ,COALESCE(MIN( CASE WHEN index_num = 3 THEN new_noterate END), in replace for NULL

Comment: It should be four single quotes instead of two as the query is inside dynamic columns list. I've updated my answer

Comment: That worked but it converts the NULLS to zero instead of just blanks, anyway around this?

Comment: That is the rates not the dates are zeros instead of NULLS

Comment: Thanks, that works but the zeros still show up, no worries I don't mean to keep bugging you

Comment: No worries. I've updated answer to show blank rates instead of zeros

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'datecount'.

Comment: Sorry now I am getting this Msg 1014, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
TOP clause contains an invalid value.

Comment: Please try now.

Comment: Same error: Msg 1014, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
TOP clause contains an invalid value.
I will happily accept your answer if you don't want to continue

Comment: I've updated the code. I moved out top number to @HowMany variable - this should help

Comment: Thanks for some reason I keep getting the same error that points to this line WITH E(n) AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n))